# Uncompress pdf issues

Tags: .net, pdf

[image]

When we decompress an pdf file we get some strange output as shown in the image.
(the pdf is opened in notepad++)

We've tried to decompress this using several libs and tools like mupdf, pdftk and 
our own .net application which decompresses all the stream using zlib.

All these options give the same result.
Anyone know how to make this more readable?

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, you can *decompress* a PDF file and most objects contained in it.

But **no**, zlib isn't the only compression method that may be used in PDF.

And **no**, not every object you successfully decompressed will necessarily be composed of simple ASCII characters. They may still contain 'binary', non-ASCII characters. And binary data (compressed or not) doesn't turn to ASCII by 'decompressing' it...

Comment: ok this sounds logic, is there any way to get the data in a readable format from this binary data? I mean adobe reader can translate this information into something usefull, so I'm sure it is possible somehow.

Answer (score 0):

The data needs mapping via the encoding to make it readable. It will appear as text in WIn encoding (which is the same as notepad) but not otherwise -why do you expect it to be readable text?

Comment: Most pdf's we've opened in notpad were completely readable, all the pdf's compressed by certain software we use are not. Even after decompressing